# British Date Formatting in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$firstdate = '2011-11-16';
$sample = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($firstdate)); 
echo $sample;
?>
```

I have a column in a table with date in this format 2011-11-16
But I need it in reverse, so I've used the following code.

The problem is that when the date is 0000-00-00, it prints 01-01-1970.
Is there a way of making it print 00-00-0000 instead? Please note that I'm looking to reverse it to British format. 00-00-0000.

Thanks

Comment: echo ($date == "0000-00-00") ? "00-00-0000" :  date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way dates are represented internally. They use what's called [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), in which the date is represented as a number of seconds after the "Unix epoch", which is 1/1/1970. This is why the `date` function (correctly) represents 0 (which is what `strtotime` returns when you pass it `0000-00-00`) as Jan 1, 1970.

The only solution I can think of is something like this:

```
<?php 
$firstdate = '2011-11-16';
$sample = $firstdate == '0000-00-00' ? '00-00-0000' : date("d-m-Y", strtotime($firstdate)); 
echo $sample;
?>
```

Comment: BTW you can still look at wikipedia if you press the Esc key right before the black screen appears.

Answer (score 1):

0000-00-00 is not a valid date. Obviously there's no month 0.

So if you use that as a placeholder for 'no date at all', then the solution is rather simple:

```
if($date==='0000-00-00') {
   echo '00-00-0000';
}
```

Comment: Actually you can pass `0` as the month (or day) and it will calculate a new date based on that. For example `strtotime('2012-00-00');` gives you Nov 30th, 2011, because it's interpreted as "Jan 1st 2012 minus one day and one month"

Comment: That's merely a side-effect of how the library calculates things though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

```
<?php 
$firstdate = '2011-11-16';
$sample = $firstdate!=='0000-00-00'?date("d-m-Y", strtotime($firstdate)):''00-00-0000; 
echo $sample;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get the empty date,reverse it.

```
if( $firstdate == '0000-00-00') $sample = strrev( $firstdate);
else
{
  $sample = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($firstdate));
}
```